# How to change body css elements inside iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I set the default body background of site to:
body {background-color: red;}

However, I am using external text input box that is displayed via an iframe and its also showing a red background.

How can I keep the red background for the site but change the background inside the iframe to white?

I tried doing something like, but it had no affect:

```
iframe body {background-color: white !important;}
document body {background-color: white !important;}
td body {background-color: white !important;}
tr body {background-color: white !important;}
```

Here is a screenshot of where the body is used: http://screencast.com/t/D2x5dFRCE

Thanks!

Comment: The content of an iframe is not affected by the CSS of the parent site.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's not possible.

If you are the owner of domain in the iframe, you can allow scross site scripting by a .htaccess.

If you are create a project like "editor", you can use this to edit iframe elements format:

```
$("#iframName").contents().find(element)
```

Comment: It is possible without .htaccess; depends on location of iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to force it using jquery?

```
$("#iFrame").contents().find("#someDiv").css({width:'450px'});
$("#iFrame").contents().find("body").css({color:'red'});
```

Comment: I just tried adding this to html but it did not work unfortunately:       <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    $("#iFrame").contents().find("body").css({color:'red'}); 
    </script>